# How to deploy filebeat to fetch nginx logs with logstash in kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, kubernetes, logstash, filebeat

I deplyed a nginx pod as deployment kind in k8s.

Now I want to deploy `filebeat` and `logstash` in the same cluster to get nginx logs.

Here are my manifest files.

nginx.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
 name: logs

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: logs
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: logs
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

filebeat.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
 name: logs

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: logs
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          host: ${NODE_NAME}
          hints.enabled: true
          templates:
            - condition.contains:
                kubernetes.namespace: logs
              config:
                - module: nginx
                  access:
                    enabled: true
                    var.paths: ["/var/log/nginx/access.log*"]
                    subPath: access.log
                    tags: ["access"]
                  error:
                    enabled: true
                    var.paths: ["/var/log/nginx/error.log*"]
                    subPath: error.log
                    tags: ["error"]

    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata:
      - add_host_metadata:

    cloud.id: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}
    cloud.auth: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}

    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["logstash:5044"]
      loadbalance: true
      index: filebeat

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: logs
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
        - name: filebeat
          image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.10.0
          args: [
            "-c", "/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml",
            "-e",
          ]
          env:
            - name: NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
              subPath: filebeat.yml
              readOnly: true
            - name: data
              mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
            - name: varlibdockercontainers
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
              readOnly: true
            - name: varlog
              mountPath: /var/log
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 0600
            name: filebeat-config
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
        - name: data
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

logstash.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
 name: logs

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: logs
  labels:
    app: logstash
  name: logstash
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "25826"
      port: 25826
      targetPort: 25826
    - name: "5044"
      port: 5044
      targetPort: 5044
  selector:
    app: logstash
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: logs
  name: logstash-configmap
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  logstash.conf: |
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
        host => "0.0.0.0"
      }
    }

    filter {
      if [fileset][module] == "nginx" {
        if [fileset][name] == "access" {
          grok {
            match => { "message" => ["%{IPORHOST:[nginx][access][remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[nginx][access][user_name]} \[%{HTTPDATE:[nginx][access][time]}\] \"%{WORD:[nginx][access][method]} %{DATA:[nginx][access][url]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[nginx][access][http_version]}\" %{NUMBER:[nginx][access][response_code]} %{NUMBER:[nginx][access][body_sent][bytes]} \"%{DATA:[nginx][access][referrer]}\" \"%{DATA:[nginx][access][agent]}\""] }
            remove_field => "message"
          }
          mutate {
            add_field => { "read_timestamp" => "%{@timestamp}" }
          }
          date {
            match => [ "[nginx][access][time]", "dd/MMM/YYYY:H:m:s Z" ]
            remove_field => "[nginx][access][time]"
          }
          useragent {
            source => "[nginx][access][agent]"
            target => "[nginx][access][user_agent]"
            remove_field => "[nginx][access][agent]"
          }
          geoip {
            source => "[nginx][access][remote_ip]"
            target => "[nginx][access][geoip]"
          }
        }
        else if [fileset][name] == "error" {
          grok {
            match => { "message" => ["%{DATA:[nginx][error][time]} \[%{DATA:[nginx][error][level]}\] %{NUMBER:[nginx][error][pid]}#%{NUMBER:[nginx][error][tid]}: (\*%{NUMBER:[nginx][error][connection_id]} )?%{GREEDYDATA:[nginx][error][message]}"] }
            remove_field => "message"
          }
          mutate {
            rename => { "@timestamp" => "read_timestamp" }
          }
          date {
            match => [ "[nginx][error][time]", "YYYY/MM/dd H:m:s" ]
            remove_field => "[nginx][error][time]"
          }
        }
      }
    }

    output {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: logstash-nginx-to-gcs
  namespace: logs
spec:
  serviceName: "logstash"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      volumes:
      - name: logstash-service-account-credentials
        secret:
          secretName: logstash-credentials
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.10.0
        volumeMounts:
        - name: logstash-service-account-credentials
          mountPath: /secrets/logstash
          readOnly: true
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 2Gi
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: logstash-nginx-to-gcs-pvc
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Ki
```

I deployed them. But I'm not sure how filebeat can fetch the nginx log in a pod. It's a DaemonSet kind.

When I check logstash's logs

```
kubectl logs -f logstash-nginx-to-gcs-0 -n logs
Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper (file:/tmp/jruby-1/jruby18310714590719622705jopenssl.jar) to field java.security.MessageDigest.provider
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-12-04T09:37:17,563][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.10.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.8+10 on 11.0.8+10 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[2020-12-04T09:37:17,659][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
[2020-12-04T09:37:17,712][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
[2020-12-04T09:37:18,748][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"8b873949-cf90-491a-b76a-e3e7caa7f593", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
[2020-12-04T09:37:20,050][WARN ][logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] xpack.monitoring.enabled has not been defined, but found elasticsearch configuration. Please explicitly set `xpack.monitoring.enabled: true` in logstash.yml
[2020-12-04T09:37:20,060][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] Internal collectors option for Logstash monitoring is deprecated and targeted for removal in the next major version.
Please configure Metricbeat to monitor Logstash. Documentation can be found at:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-with-metricbeat.html
[2020-12-04T09:37:21,056][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[2020-12-04T09:37:22,082][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2020-12-04T09:37:22,572][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
[2020-12-04T09:37:22,705][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Marking url as dead. Last error: [LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError] Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch {:url=>http://elasticsearch:9200/, :error_message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch", :error_class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError"}
[2020-12-04T09:37:22,791][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch"}
[2020-12-04T09:37:22,921][ERROR][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Failed to fetch X-Pack information from Elasticsearch. This is likely due to failure to reach a live Elasticsearch cluster.
[2020-12-04T09:37:25,467][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 262 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 23 keys and 47 values
[2020-12-04T09:37:26,613][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>125, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x726c3bee run>"}
[2020-12-04T09:37:28,365][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.74}
[2020-12-04T09:37:28,464][INFO ][logstash.inputs.beats    ][main] Beats inputs: Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5044"}
[2020-12-04T09:37:28,525][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2020-12-04T09:37:28,819][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2020-12-04T09:37:29,036][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.Server][main][0710cad67e8f47667bc7612580d5b91f691dd8262a4187d9eca8cf87229d04aa] Starting server on port: 5044
[2020-12-04T09:37:29,732][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}

[2020-12-04T09:37:52,828][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
[2020-12-04T09:37:53,109][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
```

But I don't want to connect to elasticsearch now. Just test get data.

Comment: The logstash docker image has the monitoring features configured by default and probably that's the reason it is trying to talk with elasticsearch to check the license and send metrics. Try to set `xpack.monitoring.enabled: false` in your `logstash.yml` part. You can also use the `oss` docker image since you just want to test the pipeline.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thank you for your answer. But I also didn't get nginx log. Is it right about my config or usage?

Comment: Filebeat can't read log files from Nginx logfile, Mount the logs from nginx to host, and from host to filebeat, then it can harvest. I see no files mounted to filebeat.

Comment: @JinnaBalu Yes, you are right. I created a file mount. It works. Could you write it as an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: I can write in docker-compose format but not in Kubernetes.